# how to test fluent validations error message

Tags: tdd, fluentvalidation

I am trying to get to grips with TDD, I have reviewed some tutorials and am trying to implement tests on my validation classes that I have created using fluent validation.

```
public SomeFormValidator()
{
        RuleFor(x => x.MyClass).NotNull()
            .WithMessage("MyClass cannot be null");
}
```

I have looked at the TDD examples specifically for fluent validation and created a couple of tests

```
    [Test]
    public void Should_have_error_when_MyClass_is_null()
    {
        MyClass myClass = null;
        SomeFormValidator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(aup => aup.MyClass, myClass);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Should_not_have_error_when_MyClass_is_not_null()
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        SomeFormValidator.ShouldNotHaveValidationErrorFor(aup => aup.MyClass, myClass);
    }
```

I would like to now test that the string "MyClass cannot be null" is returned when it is null. I have not been able to find anything covering returned message and I have not been able to work it out.

Comment: Please provide a full validator class

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to the guidance of @Surgey I was able to come up with a solution that uses the fluent validation built in methods, in addition to that I have been able to better layout my test which I have added below

```
using FluentValidation.TestHelper;
using NUnit.Framework;
using MyProject.Models...
using MyProject...

namespace MyProject.Tests.Classes.Validation
{
[TestFixture]
public class SomeFormValidatorTest
{
    private SomeFormValidator SomeFormValidator;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        SomeFormValidator = new SomeFormValidator();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Should_display_correct_error_message_MyClass_is_null()
    {
        //arrange
        MyClass myClass = null;

        //act
        var result = SomeFormValidator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.MyClass, myClass);

        //assert
        result.WithErrorMessage("MyClass is required");

        //first attempt prior to finding WithErrorMessage exists
        //foreach (var r in result)
        //{
        //    Assert.AreEqual("MyClass is required", r.ErrorMessage);
        //}
    }
}
```

}

I am using `result.WithErrorMessage` as that is was is provided in the result but I have left the foreach in, but commented, as I find the error message produced by using `Assert.AreEqual` produce a better message in the test runner.

Answer (score 3):

There is Arrange-Act-Assert ([AAA](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrangeActAssert)) technique that helps to structure unit tests properly.

### Arrange

First of all, you need to create a System Under Test ([SUT](http://xunitpatterns.com/SUT.html)) and *inputs*. In this case that are `SomeFormValidator` and `SomeForm` instances:

```
  // arrange
  var sut = new SomeFormValidator();
  var someFormWithNullProp = new SomeForm { MyClass = null };
```

### Act

Then you need to call the SUT to perform real work. For [validators](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation#example), that is the `Validate()` method call:

```
  // act
  ValidationResult result = sut.Validate<SomeForm>(someFormWithNullProp);
```

### Assert

The last part of the unit test checks if the actual result matches the expectations:

```
  // assert
  Assert.False(result.IsValid);
  Assert.AreEqual(
    "MyClass cannot be null",
    result.Errors.Single().ErrorMessage);
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing it up. I noticed that all tdd tutorial taught the AA technique, yet it confused me that the fluent validation tutorials seemed no to use that technique. So it left me under the impression that using their methods abstracted that technique from the tester

Comment: FluentValidation tutorials show you how to use the _library API_. They are not supposed to show you their unit tests (that exist _only_ for the library needs in order to guarantee it works properly).